# How to use a PocketSphinx to recognize several keywords in Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I would like to have a PocketSphinx implementation of speech recognition to recognize key phrases such as 'yes', 'no', 'i dont know', 'probably', 'probably'.

I looked over the official documentation. I see that I will need to define my dictionary. But I don't know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python detect keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246786/python-detect-keywords)

Comment: "yes" is too short for a keyword